# How to use the Cognito SDK with a Lambda function to fetch the JWT access token

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

I already created a User Pool in Amazon Cognito and now I want to fetch the JWT access token using an AWS Lambda function, but I don't know how to do this.

How can I use the Cognito SDK with the Lambda function to fetch the JWT access token?

Comment: There are many tutorials like this one https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o7OHogUcRmI which should be able to clear this answer.

Comment: What do you need the access token in your Lambda for?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.